# How to convert any JSON object to C# object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have few different JSON objects.

### Fist JSON object

```
{
    "api": {
    "NAME":"CUSTOMER_CREATE",
    "QUERY":"CUSTOMER_CREATE"
 },
 "header" : {
    "PartyNumber": "1488002",
    "OrganizationName": "Test Organization-02",
    "RawPhoneNumber": "9199199199",
    "PartyUsageCode": "EXTERNAL_LEGAL_ENTITY",
    "Address": [
{
    "AddressType": "BILL_TO",
    "Address1": "77 College Rd",
    "Address2": "London NW10 5SE",
    "Address3": "London NW10 5SF",
    "Address4": "London NW10 5SG",
    "City": "London",
    "Country": "GB",
    "PostalCode": "NW10 5ES"
}
```

### Second JSON object

```
 "api": {
        "NAME":"ITEM_CREATE",
        "QUERY":"ITEM_CREATE"
     },
"header" : 
{
"OrganizationCode": "IM_MASTER_ORG",
"ItemClass" : "Root Item Class",
"ItemNumber" : "TEST-01",
"ItemDescription" : "TEST-01",
"ItemStatusValue" : "Active",
"PrimaryUOMValue" : "Each",
"LifecyclePhaseValue" : "Production"
}
```

Also I have many JSON objects like this. All JSON object are not same. So I want to write One C# class for convert this any JSON object to C# Object. So can you please me one class to convert these JSON object.

Currently I am using this class to convert Json object. but I want to make this as a dynamic class

```
public class MHScaleMessage {

    //public string api { get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> api { get; set;}  = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> header {get; set; }  = new Dictionary<string, string>();                 
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> lineItems { get; set; } = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    public static string GetValue(Dictionary<string, string> d, string key, string defaultVal="") {
        if (key == null) return defaultVal;
        return d.TryGetValue(key, out string val) ? val : defaultVal;
    }

    public static int GetValueAsInt(Dictionary<string, string> d, string key, int defaultVal=0) {
        if (key == null) return defaultVal;
        string val = d.TryGetValue(key, out val) ? val : null;
        if (val == null) return defaultVal;
        return int.TryParse(val, out _) ? 0 : defaultVal;
    }

    public string ToJsonString() {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            WriteIndented = true,
            IgnoreNullValues = true
        };
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(this, options));
    }
    
    public  string _ToString() {
        string s="";
        s += "{"; s += "\n";
        s += "api = " + api; s += ","; s += "\n";
        s += "header ="; s += "\n";
        s += "{";
        header.ToList().ForEach(x => s += x.Key + " = " + x.Value + "\n");
        s += "}"; s += ","; s += "\n";
        s += "lineItems"; s += "\n";
        s += "{"; s += "[";
        lineItems.ForEach(x => {
            x.ToList().ForEach(y => {
                s += y.Key + " = " + y.Value; 
                s += ","; s += "\n";
            }
            );
        });
        s += "]";  s += "}"; s += "\n";
        s += "}";
        return s;
    }       
}
```

After that I am using following method to perform API. to this method I can pass parameter.

```
  private static MHScaleMessage PerformAPIFunction(MHScaleMessage requestObj)
    {}
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json .
as a rule of thumb, you should ask questions with a small code example, so people can help you figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to convert a JSON object to a C# sharp object and here I am going to show a few ways.

**One Line Code**

```
var oMycustomclassname = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

If you have your own class then change `var` to your own class.

**Use JSON.NET**

There is a recommended way to convert JSON to C# object and that is [JSON.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)
Have a look at the github repo to get more information. Here is an example for your case.

```
public class User
{
public User(string json)
{
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    JToken jUser = jObject["api"];
    name = (string) jUser["NAME"];
    query = (string) jUser["QUERY"];
    JToken jUser1 = jObject["header"];
    OrganizationCode = (string) jUser1["OrganizationCode"];
    ItemClass = (string) jUser1["ItemClass"];
    ItemNumber = jUser1["ItemNumber"];
}

public string api_Name{ get; set; }
public string api_Query { get; set; }
public string header_OrganizationCode{ get; set; }
public string header_ItemClass{ get; set; }
}

// Use
private void Run()
{
string json = @"{"api": {
    "NAME":"ITEM_CREATE",
    "QUERY":"ITEM_CREATE"
 },
"header" : 
{
"OrganizationCode": "IM_MASTER_ORG",
"ItemClass" : "Root Item Class",
"ItemNumber" : "TEST-01",
"ItemDescription" : "TEST-01",
"ItemStatusValue" : "Active",
"PrimaryUOMValue" : "Each",
"LifecyclePhaseValue" : "Production"
 }";
User user = new User(json);

Console.WriteLine("Name : " + user.name);
Console.WriteLine("Teamname : " + user.teamname);
Console.WriteLine("Email : " + user.email);
Console.WriteLine("Players:");

foreach (var player in user.players)
    Console.WriteLine(player);
}
```

Comment: How can I use above class for convert to all JSON object. I have update question with my current class that I have use for the convert JSON to C#. Can you please update that class to dynamic class. then I don't want to mention anything like above. automatically convert Json to C# object. Then I can use that parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can get your requirement easily by using Newtonsoft.Json library. I am writing down the one example below have a look into it.

**Class for the type of object you receive:**

```
public class Student
 {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

**Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   string json = "{\"ID\": 1, \"Name\": \"Abdullah\"}";
   Student student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);

   Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Simple way to parse your json.